# Two containers need to be the same size...and yet they aren't : why?

Tags: css, size

I'm trying to make a project.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    max-width: 890px;
    margin:auto;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Sylfaen;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin:auto;
    width:890px;
    height: 50%;
    background:url(header2.jpg) no-repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 3%;
    border-top-right-radius: 3%;
}

.SUB {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #000
    padding-top: 30px;

}
.Titre {
    font-family: Downcome;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

.main-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 296.6px;
    background-color: black;
    text-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.main-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu ul li a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
     color: red;
}

ul li ul li{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 296.6px;

}

ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    max-height: 50%;
}

.content{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.97);
}
```

https://codepen.io/julian-van-garden/pen/eYmyZJJ?fbclid=IwAR0Rb8MZS5PAhAh1sPkBiPDAAvZPn325gYxfbT9ws_R5UT8WqhUma9JojOI
I tried to use percentage at first as I would have like something responsive...Then I gave up.
Basically the menu and the logo need to be the exact same size : in the code, to my knowledge, they are 890px.
And yet when previewed in the browser, the menu does not have the same length.
Can someone tell me why?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this. You can play with the width and font-size to dial it in.

```
.main-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width:15%;
    background-color: black;
    text-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:18px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment from structure of interested code is:

```
.main-menu ul li ul {
  height:200px;
}
```

every `<ul>` have `li`, which have `a` as a child.

Every `a` has 50px

- In first (Le Groupe) : 2a = 100px
- In second(Sa Musique) : 4a = 200px

For three levels you should use `<ol>`

For `ol` `ul` `li` hierarchy

---

Just if You add, it's works:

```
.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  height:200px;
}
```